# WDS with multiple partitions

Tags: windows-10, windows-server-2012-r2

Trying to capture a Win10 image with multiple partitions. Only one OS, second partition is D: data drive and 3rd is A: data drive, both secondary partitions are required for certain programs.

Environment: Windows 10 on Dell Latitude 5570
250GB partitioned as C:, D:, a:

WDS:
server 2012R2
MDT isntalled

However, from what I've read the WDS capture is only capturing the C: drive. Is there not a way to capture the entire hard drive, including partitions?